# How do I programmatically detect the different states of a call in ' call waiting' mode, in android?

Tags: android

With PhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged , I am getting the states CALL_STATE_RINGING with incoming number and  CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK but how do we know when the user switches between calls? Is there any method to check which number is 'on hold' and which number is 'on call'?